# SharePoint 2013 email templates

Tags: 2013, development, email, alert, template

I have a SharePoint 2013 instance that I would like to modify the default email template.  I want to put my `company's logo` as a header and the company contact info as a footer on every email that is sent from SharePoint.

Is there any way to force SharePoint to use my message template?  If there is an event receiver that I can tap into, that would also work.

I am a C# developer, so if there is some custom code required, I'd actually prefer it.

Comment: With SP 2016, using a template that worked in SP 2013, no alerts where sent at all. Anyone has a (none server side code) solution? BTW some of the links here do not work anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a developer you have several ways to customize the alerts.

In order to insert your company's logo, you will have to implement your own iAlertNotifyHandler.

You can get an overview about your possibilities here: "msdn Library > Alerts in SharePoint Foundation"

The article says nothing about SharePoint 2013, but when you look in the documentation for "msdn Library > SharePoint schemas > AlertTemplates schema", you'll find that it still works with SharePoint 2013.

Here are two tutorials that should help you:

- [How to: How To: Customizing alert emails using IAlertNotifyHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2010 custom alert template](http://blog.zebsadiq.com/post/SharePoint-2010-custom-alert-template.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is few change in the C# code used for SharePoint 2013. Here is step by step guide for implementing it in SharePoint 2013.

http://sharepointrealm.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-cusomize-alert-email-for.html