# SP2013 Customize email body of all alerts

Tags: 2013, alert, custom-alert-templates

How to create your own email content for all the alerts emails which are sent OOTB .
I need to modify the email content of all the alerts send OOTB (The immediate emails, update email , delete email , daily summary alert email and weekly summary alert ) . 
I know of creating copy of alerttemplate.xml and editing it but how to ensure all email alerts content are modified .

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered here [SharePoint 2013 email templates](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60547/sharepoint-2013-email-templates)

and here a good blog post on this

http://www.alectang.com/blog/archive/2012/05/16/how-to-customise-sharepoint-alert-email-template.aspx